# parse file just before compilation

Tags: c++, gcc

there is any option in gcc compiler which can call my function just before compilation starts so i can inject some code in files.

**Note: Macros are not able to solve my problem because they are not able process anything.**

scenario :-

```
@somthing1
class classname{
  @somthing2
  setsome(int val){
  }
}
```

in this code i want remove these @ notations and wants to inject a code. i can do it via script but if gcc compiler provide some way so it will be very useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose also a shell script might suffice if that's a simple parsing operation. Otherwise you would need a precompilation stage

Comment: Write a program (in whatever language you want) that does what you want, invoke it in your build system before invoking the compiler?

Comment: gcc provides lots of option, but i didn't find out related to this. script can solve my problem. but i want to know if compiler provide option.

Comment: Have you looked at template meta-programming? Also, macros are pretty powerful, though a pain to debug. David’s approach of using Makefiles is probably the best bet, but you didn’t tell us enough to make a good guess.

Comment: i have used template meta-programming. but can u tell me if i am missing something so i can solve this problem with templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a gcc plugin. After about version 4.6, gcc supported the use of user-written plugins that are invoked in the "middle-end" of the compiler. You can manipulate the source in any way that you want, but you have to work with the GIMPLE intermediate representation. You can add statements, delete statements, change datatypes, whatever you like.

Comment: Please explain the downvote! I was quite serious about this answer, and I written a plugin that does what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

- First solution: What about a pre-building stage for a makefile (if you're using it) ?

  ```
  CC=gcc

  all: pre-build main-build

  pre-build:
      @echo PRE

  main-build: target

  target: $(OBJS) 
        $(CC) -o ...
  ```
- Second solution: if you're using something else like **CMake** to generate your makefile then you might use CMake's APIs to do pre-build operations and/or to extend your makefile.
- Third solution: do it via **shell script**, something like sed also supports regex so you should be set for a pretty decent parser.
- Fourth solution: use a **python** [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3253522/1938163) invoked before compilation stage. This is probably overkill but should indeed suffice for any parsing need.